# Error [Plugin.hh:138] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_camera.so: libCameraPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello guys, I have the following issue on gazebo 1.9 (ROS Hydro - Ubuntu 12.04):
I have a package, for example pioneer3at, where in .sdf file some plugin, as libgazebo_ros_camera.so, are inserted.
When I type
roslaunch pioneer3at myfile.launch

it gives me this error

```
Msg Waiting for masterMsg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 172.20.242.19
Error [Plugin.hh:138] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_camera.so: libCameraPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried also to set env variable GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH correctly but however it doesn't work. However I noted that, in a tutorial of gazebo about RRBot Example, when I typed roslaunch command, it gave me the same error but with a several plugin:

```
Error [Plugin.hh:138] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so:libgazebo_ros_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To resolve this last problem, I installed ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control package.
Now my question is: to resolve the problem with libgazebo_ros_camera.so:libCameraPlugin.so, I should install a missing package or what?
This is really important for me...
Excuse me and thanks to all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6075/error-%5Bplugin.hh:138%5D--failed-to-load-plugin-libgazebo_ros_camera.so:-libcameraplugin.so:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Il_Voza](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/751/il_voza/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `gazebo_ros_packages` (or ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs) should contain the plugin.

If the gazebo_ros_control plugin can be found this will solve the problem...

The whole installation procedure is described here: [`Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages`](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages)

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0